# Does For Honor support cross-play between Steam and Uplay?

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, for-honor

For Honor can be bought from Steam and Uplay as far as I know. However, if I buy the game on Uplay, am I able to play with my friends who bought it on Steam?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Honor, like many other Ubisoft titles, on PC runs only on the Uplay platform. Steam purchases require launching Uplay and linking the purchase to a Uplay account. You should have no trouble matchmaking with your friends provided you're friends on Uplay.